# Integrability of an alternating series with hypergeometric coefficients

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

during my research, I came up with the following series
$$
f(t):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-t^2\right)^k}{(k!)^2}{}_3F_{2}\left(\left(-k,-k,-k\right);\left(1,\frac{1}{2}-k\right);\frac{1}{4}\right),\quad t\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
I want to show that this series is integrable, i.e.
$$
\int_1^\infty |f(t)| d t <\infty.
$$
(The choice of the lower bound 1 is intended)

**My idea so far:**
Since $(-k)$ is a non-positive integer, we can write the hypergeometric function as a finite series
$$
{}_3F_{2}\left(\left(-k,-k,-k\right);\left(1,\frac{1}{2}-k\right);\frac{1}{4}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(k!)^4(2(k-j))!}{(2k)!((k-j)!)^4 4^j (j!)^2}.
$$
I tried to approximate that using the Stirling formula $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$, but it did not turned out well.
Numerically, I found a **possible** integrable upper bound $|f(t)|<\left|\frac{J_0(t)}{t^{0.5+\epsilon}}\right|$ for some small $\epsilon>0$ (the roots do not coincide perfectly, but it looks like a matter of shift).
Has someone seen such a series before? Could you help me how to prove the integrability?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You might want to check your formula, where you break down the $_{3}F_{2}$ to a sum. I suspect, there is a factor $4^{j}$ too much in the denominator of the summand.

Comment: (twice edited comment) It is quite easy to show that $_{3} F_{2}\left(-k,-k,-k;1,\frac{1}{2}-k;\frac{1}{4}\right)\sim\sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi}} \ \frac{3}{4\ \sqrt{k}} \ \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{2 k}$ for large $k$. (sorry, for the repeated edits)

Comment: I found two other forms of the generalized hypergeometric function: first $_{3}F_{2}\left( -k,-k,-k;1,\frac{1}{2}-k;\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{k!^{2}}{(2 k)!}\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{2j}{j} \ \binom{k}{j}^{2}$

Comment: .... and the second is: $F_{2}\left(-k,-k,-k;\frac{1}{2}-k,1;\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{k!^{2}}{(2 k)!} \ _{3}F_{2}\left(\frac{1}{2},-k,-k;1,1;4\right)$